# Can AzCopy upload a directory to blob storage while setting file-specific metadata on each file?

Tags: azcopy

I want to upload a directory of files to blob storage. I need to maintain the folder structure, as it's important.

```
PS C:\UploadFolder> tree /F
C:.
└───DocumentsForUpload
    └───Identifier
        ├───Identifier2-1
        │       doc1.pdf
        │
        ├───Identifier2-2
        │       doc1.docx
        │       doc2.doc
        │
        └───Identifier2-3
                etc
```

I'd also like to preserve the last modified date on the documents. Setting that date on the metadata is acceptable. I know azcopy can set metadata like this:

```
azcopy copy "individual_file_path" "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/test1/aaa1.txt?sasToken" --metadata "lastmodified=2023-08-15 04:43:36"
```

so theoretically I could use a powershell script and run an individual azcopy for every file in the folder, but that feels wrong.

Is there a way for azcopy to set the metadata based on a property of the current file being uploaded to blob storage?